# Irregular spacing of self-defined paragraphs

Tags: line-spacing

Consider the following command, intended to introduce a new paragraph similar to `\paragraph`.

```
\newcommand\ITEM[1]{\smallskip\par\noindent\textit{#1.}}
```

The problem: If the preceding paragraph ends with a line that completely fills the line (but no overfull hbox), then the inter-paragraph space becomes larger. What's missing in this definition such that it produces equally spaced paragraphs?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ITEM[1]{\smallskip\par\noindent\textit{#1.}}
\begin{document}
  \ITEM{A} Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
  \ITEM{B} Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Ab.
  \ITEM{C} Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `\vspace` in vertical mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ITEM[1]{\par\smallskip\noindent\textit{#1.}}
\begin{document}
  \ITEM{A} Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
  \ITEM{B} Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Ab.
  \ITEM{C} Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the original version if you did not add a blank line before `\ITEM` then the `\smallskip` is added after the space token at the end of the previous line and you can end up with a final line of the paragraph that just has the space.

Comment: Oh. That simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The original version have `\smallskip` as a first token of `\ITEM`. The `\ITEM` is used as the first object of next line. So, we have `Ab.<space>\ITEM`. Because `\smallskip` is defined as `\vskip something` and TeX itself puts `\par` before `\vskip` if it is not in vertical mode, we have `Ab.<space>\par\vskip...` The `\par` finalizes the paragraph. First feature of built-in algorithm of `\par` is removing the (possible) last space, so we have `... Ab.<build paragraph>`. I don't understand why there is the empty line in the original example.

Comment: @wipet  this is latex (I know, not your favourite format:-) note my first line `\smallskip` is `\vspace{\smallskipamount}` which puts the vskip in a vadjust in hmode.